How do assign TIMER command to BOT through HEXCHAT?
I found this - How Timer command works in HEXCHAT
I am using the timer command to send the period messages. I want to assign it bot to send this using HEXCHAT. How do I do this?
I m using below command
/timer -repeat 3 3600 say "msg"
However this needs me to be logged in for it to work. The Channel has the bot and I want to know If there is a command in HEXchat that allows bot to send the same command?
